# Erasure vs implicit cast for multiple bounded types in a Generic Class/Method

Tags: java, generics, jls, erasure

According to [JLS§4.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4):

> The order of types in a bound is only significant in that the erasure of a type variable is determined by the first type in its bound, and that a class type or type variable may only appear in the first position.

Consider the following snippet:

```java
package TypeVarMembers;

class C { 
    public    void mCPublic()    {}
    protected void mCProtected() {} 
              void mCPackage()   {}
    private   void mCPrivate()   {} 
} 

interface I {
    void mI();
}

class CT extends C implements I {
    public void mI() {}
}

class Test {
    <T extends C & I> void test(T t) {  
        t.mI();           // OK
        t.mCPublic();     // OK 
        t.mCProtected();  // OK 
        t.mCPackage();    // OK
        //t.mCPrivate();    // Compile-time error
    } 
}
```

Here are some doubts that I have-:

1. **Erasure for method `test(T t)` => `test(C t)`?**

   - if this is the case - then **why are we dropping the additional types while computing Erasure?**
2. **Implicit cast for the type `T` in method `test(T t)` => `(C & I)`?**
3. Theoretically **is the erasure same as the implicit cast**?

Comment: I don't understand your first question. How is the erasure of `T` being `C` related to "why are we dropping the additional types while computing Erasure"?

Comment: The erasure of `T` is indeed `C`. We drop `I` according to JLS§4.4, because that is the second type in the bounds list.

Comment: Method signatures aren't erased. You need all the generic Information in the bytecode so that the compiler can know that e.g. `List<E>.add(E)` requires an `E`, not just any `Object`.

Comment: @Andy - agree on that part - but what I am more interested in knowing is that why Erasure is not same as the implicit cast?